# Permission not granted when delete file

Tags: linux, jenkins, cleanup

I am trying to run clean jenkins workspace with `rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/*` but I get permission denied for `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/*`

I see `jenkins jenkins` when I execute `ll` to check which user is owner of these file

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The typical `ll` alias for the `ls` command doesn't include the ls `-a` switch to display hidden files. There may be "hidden" files or files deeper in the directory tree owned by another user that cause the permission denied error. `find /var/lib/jenkins/workspace -ls` might be convenienyt to list all files

Comment: Check the permission of the directory as well. To delete files from a directory, you need to have write access for the directory itself (in your case, you need to be able to write the `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/` directory).